# AspectJ annotations are not working in JAVA maven project (Not spring project)

Tags: aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm trying to implement AspectJ annotations in JAVA maven project without spring. I have added Aspects and create annotation. But its not invoking the Aspects where i have added as Annotation to the method..Below is my code..Also the project link - https://github.com/chandru-kumar/aop-example

I have added aspectj maven plugin as well..But its not getting invoked..Can you pls help..? Not sure what I'm missing.
I haven't found any example without Spring project..

Pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aop.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>aop-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.aop.example.Test
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JAVA - Aspects - Advice

```java
package com.aop.advices;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;

public class SysoutAdvice {
    @Around("@annotation(com.annotations.Sysout)")
    public Object print(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Start....");
        Object object = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("End....");
        return object;
    }
}
```

JAVA - Annotation

```java
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@retention(RUNTIME)
@target(METHOD)
public @interface Sysout{}
```

Comment: Here is the example code - [AOP Example](https://github.com/chandru-kumar/aop-example)

Comment: Thanks for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. This was exactly the right thing to do. Otherwise it would have been impossible that I notice all those errors within a few minutes. Actually, answering the question and documenting it by screenshots took much longer than actually fixing the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell that you are an AspectJ beginner. You made many mistakes. But do not worry, you are going to learn and get more experience over time.

#### Annotation must have `RUNTIME` scope

Otherwise the compiled code will not have an annotation to intercept, only the source code, which does not help.

[image]

#### Aspect must have `@Aspect` annotation

Otherwise the AspectJ compiler will not identify the class as an aspect.

[image]

#### Avoid double log output

If you do not add `&& execution(* *(..))`, the aspect will intercept both `call` and `execution` joinpoints. The effect would be double log messages, because the aspect advice is triggered twice.

[image]

#### Add missing Maven plugin execution

Otherwise the AspectJ Maven plugin does not compile anything, because you did not tell it what to do.

[image]

#### Delete redundant AspectJ dependencies

Otherwise the Assembly plugin will pack them into the executable JAR, blowing it up to size 13.4 MB. But actually, you only need the AspectJ runtime `aspectjrt` in order to run an application when using compile-time weaving. The other two are for load-time weaving (`aspectjweaver`) and for the AspectJ compiler (`aspetjtools`), both of which you do not need during runtime.

If you follow my advice to remove those two, the JAR size shrinks dramatically to 0.12 MB. That is more than a factor 100 smaller.

[image]

#### Make sure the old AspectJ Maven plugin uses an up-to-date AspectJ compiler

The version number should be the same as the one used for `aspectjrt`. So you do not need `aspetjtools` as a runtime dependency, but as a plugin dependency, if you want to make sure you have identical versions.

[image]

This step is optional, but AspectJ Maven 1.11 uses AspectJ Tools 1.8.13 by default. This is fine if you just compile Java 8 code, because AspectJ Maven 1.11 does not support more than Java 8.

If you want a more modern plugin supporting AspectJ 1.9.7.M3 and Java 16, please look at the [`dev.aspectj` plugin version](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin) (please note the other Maven group ID!).

There are other suboptimal things that should be changed in your Maven configuration, but this is the most important stuff, which makes your project run and your executable JAR small.

---

**Update:** Here is my [pull request](https://github.com/chandru-kumar/aop-example/pull/1) which fixes the problems above and a few more (see commit comments).

Comment: **Update:** I created a GitHub pull request and added a link to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex. The example code works! I understand that i will have to grab the basics first and then start creating sample projects. Thanks a lot for taking time and explaining the basic stuffs and updating my example code.. It helps a lot..!!

Comment: Also when i run the code from Eclipse as Java Program, the aspects are not getting called. Is there a plugin for AspectJ in Eclipse to make it work? I can mvn package the jar and run it and it works..Just wanted to know, if we have any options in Eclipse....

Comment: Did you try a Web search engine? Look for AJDT.

Comment: It is very impressive the effort that you make on your AspectJ related answers

Comment: @dreamcrash, I always hope that it teaches other users who may find this, too, i.e. I am not writing it for the OP's benefit only. Actually, I was amazed at how many things at once can be done wrong in such a small example project. But being small, makes it a wonderful example, educating beginners about which details to be careful about when trying "copy & paste programming". Software development is all about the details, is it not? 

Comment: @kriegaex Indeed it is, that and the devil :D. It is is to be praised what you do for the AspectJ tag, it helps to keep it alive and also helps that people don't give up on the technology for lack of support

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing this in your pom.xml---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.aop</groupId>
  <artifactId>AOPconcept</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>AOPconcept</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

<dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context 
-->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.9.9.1</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.9.1</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>1.3</version>  
    <configuration>  
      <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>  
    </configuration>  
    <executions>  
    </executions>  
  </plugin>  

   </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```